# Property returning null unless It's bound?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

```
         Window2 X = new Window2();
        var taskViewModel = (XViewModel)X.DataContext;
        taskViewModel.Name = Username;
        X.Show();
```

I struggled for hours thinking that the above code is not working properly while It was. 
Because If I bind `Name` to a Textblock for example in the second form, the value is going to show. If I write it using `Console.Write` or try to show it in a `MessageBox` It returns null, nothing is shown. What is causing that?

```
 public string Name
      {
          get { return _Name; }
          set
          {
              _Name = value;
              NotifyOfPropertyChange("Name");
          }
      }

     Public XViewModel()
    {
        MessageBox.Show(Name);
    }
```

As simpel as that, the above messageBox will be empty. If I do this however:

```
<TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Name}" ></TextBlock>
```

It's going to show properly as soon as I open the window using the first code.

**EDIT:** I tried to make a button and binded a command that calls the MessageBox. In this case, Name is **showing propertly**.

EDIT2: this is not working either:

```
        Window2 w = new Window2();
        XViewModel vm = new XViewModel ();
        vm.Name = Username;
        w.DataContext = vm;
        w.Show();
```

Comment: How are you setting `DataContext` to your `Window2`?

Comment: Inside the constructor, Name is null if you don't set it properly.

Comment: Apart from the code above? In code-behind, I have DataContext = new XViewModel();

Comment: It seems like you are calling the constructor with the MessageBox.Show(Name) before you set the DataContext, therefore it is null. Put a breakpoint in your constructor and put another one in your _Name = value; in your Name setter, you will see how it flows :)

Comment: @JuanCarlosRodriguez The work-around in this case? the DataContext is set in the code-behind.

Comment: @Hackawar if you put a breakpoint in the MessageBox.Show(Name) and watch the call stack you can see from where you are calling it. Then put a breakpoint in your Name setter and you can see from where you are calling it. I bet you are setting the name after you call the constructor ( logic  :D )

Comment: You are calling `MessageBox.Show(Name);` in the constructor of `XViewModel`, which is called here `XViewModel vm = new XViewModel ();`, i.e. before username is set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are tring to show Name inside the constructor that is before you set the property:

```
    // Here i think you are creating XViewModel
    Window2 X = new Window2();

    //Here where the Messagebox shows

    var taskViewModel = (XViewModel)X.DataContext;

    //Here you set the property
    taskViewModel.Name = Username;

    // Now the value is correctly shown in the textblock
    X.Show();
```

Try setting the value of the property after you create the object XViewModel:

```
public class Window2
{
   public Window2(XViewModel vm)
   {
       InitializeComponent();

       DataContext = vm;
   }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Let's do something else:

Define **XViewModel** class this way:

```
public class XViewModel
{
   public XViewModel(String nameProp)
   {
      Name = nameProp;
      MessageBox.Show(Name);
    }
   // Your Properties
   // Your Methods
}


// Create XViewModel and pass it to Window 2
var taskViewModel = new XViewModel(Username);   //HERE where messagebox shows

Window2 X = new Window2(taskViewModel);

// Now the value is correct shown in the textblock
X.Show();
```

Comment: Like I said its flow is correct but he is trying to get the property before he initializes it :)

Comment: That didn't solve it sadly. It's still showing an empty MessageBox.

Comment: @Hackawar did you pass the taskViewModel to Window2 as i explained in the answer? It's true! It will always show you an empty messagebox

Comment: @Babbillumpa I did exactly that yes.

Comment: @Hackawar see the edited answer: try to modify XViewModel class and pass the string to the constructor.

Comment: @Hackawar Believe me, debug it putting breakpoints and watching your call stack, and you will see your app flow. Seems like you don't really know how it's flowing when you create your new window

Comment: @JuanCarlosRodriguez Sadly, I don't know how to do otherwise I would've done it but I will give it a try even though the edited solution worked.

Comment: @Babbillumpa That worked but why is the "Here you set the property" line is still necessary? and btw, you forgot to add "Username" when you're creating the viewModel. Edit: nevermind, you fixed it.

Comment: @Hackawar i didn't write the whole code, just a piece to let you understand. No, if you use the edit version, that line is no more usefull because, you are passing the UserName to the constructor of the XViewModel

Comment: You should know how breakpoints and call stack work, it will solve most of your issues. I give you a few links :) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5557y8b4.aspx  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512758/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-call-stack-window-in-visual-studio

Comment: @Babbillumpa Understood. Any downsides for the new method by the way?

Comment: @JuanCarlosRodriguez Time to read then, I appreciate your help!

Comment: @Hackawar Your welcome ;) it will help you as you will know step by step from where you came

Comment: @Hackawar, there are a lot of ways to achieve what you want, i think that this is a very good way.

Comment: @Babbillumpa Thank you so much for the help. :)